# How to access a ruby file from another directory

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am having two Folder name `Folder1` and `Folder2`.

In `Folder1` I am having ruby File `File1.rb` and in `Folder2` I am having `File2.rb`. I want to use method inside `File1.rb` to `File2.rb`.

When I try using `require_relative 'File1.rb'` in `File2.rb` it says it cannot able to access the file. What code I need to use to access `File1.rb`?

*Note:* If both files are in same folder, `require_relative` is working fine. But on different folder it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The word “relative” means exactly what is says:

```
require_relative '../Folder1/File1.rb'
```

Comment: Hi.. Its working now. I missed ../ before folder1. Thank you. The code works even without adding extension .rb

Answer (score 1):

`require_relative` complements the builtin method `require` by allowing you to load a file that is relative to the file containing the `require_relative` statement.

Let's say that your folder structure is:

```
Folder

  Folder1
    File1.rb

  Folder2
    File2.rb
```

then your statement where you require File1.rb in File2.rb needs to be

> require_relative '../Folder1/File1'

Comment: Hi.. Its working now. I missed ../ before folder1. Thank you